# Parsing SOAP XML in SQL Server 

Tags: sql-server, xml, soap

I'm trying to get the 'Response' text from a SOAP response in SQL Server but I cannot use soap:Envelope because of Parsing error's from SQL Server.

> XML parsing error: Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'soap'.

My XML Response is as follows and is contained in an nvarchar called @xmlOut:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <Method1Response xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <Method1Result>&lt;Interface&gt;&lt;Col1&gt;#result#&lt;/Col1&gt;&lt;Col2&gt;info&lt;/Col2&gt;&lt;Col3&gt;Record is invalid.&lt;/Col3&gt;&lt;Col4&gt;&lt;/Col4&gt;&lt;/Interface&gt;</Method1Result>
  </Method1Response>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am trying to get Method1Result into an nvarchar but I am really struggling with reading this XML.

```
declare @xDoc as xml
set @xDoc = cast(@xmlOut as xml)

declare @hdoc int
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @xDoc

select *
from 
(   select *
    from openxml(@hdoc, '/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/MethodResponse', 1) 
    with (MethodResult nvarchar(max)) 
) as x

exec sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

This is how I normally read my XML variables in SQL, but as soon as I try to read soap:Envelope I get this error :

> XML parsing error: Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'soap'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2005 or later you can do this instead.

```
;with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soap],
                    default 'http://tempuri.org/')
select T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
from @xDoc.nodes('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/Method1Response/Method1Result') as T(N)
```

Or a bit simpler/faster if you only expect value of Method1Result in the XML.

```
;with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soap],
                    default 'http://tempuri.org/')
select @xDoc.value('(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/Method1Response/Method1Result)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: As a secondary question, how do you use the above example to get the faultstring text from soap:Fault.

I thought this would do it, but it's not returning any values at all.

;with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soap],
                    default 'http://tempuri.org/')
select @xDoc.value('(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/faultstring)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')

Comment: @Elarys - XML is case sensitive. Perhaps it should be `FaultString`.

Comment: I tried that too, but the xml returned is `<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; The remote name could not be resolved: 'remote01'</faultstring>
      <detail />
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>`

Hmm, I can't seem to get @Mikael to work too.

Comment: @Elarys You are missing `http://` in the beginning of the xmlnamespace and `faultstring` is not part of the default namespace. This will work for you. `;with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as [soap]) 
select @xDoc.query('/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/soap:Fault/faultstring')`

Comment: @Mikeal Ahh that works. The 'http://' got stripped out of my first comment as a hyperlink. Turns out I just needed to remove the default namespace. I thought I needed it in because my WebService has that namespace, obviously I only need that when I get a successful response. Thanks again.